# Why is there a "nous" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I was reading this forum post about the difference between il existe and il y a, but I came across a sentence I really couldn't wrap my head around:

> Je m'explique un peu plus : **certainement nous arrive-t-il à tous de dire il existe**, il n'existe pas sans intention particulière, et dans ce cas la nuance avec il y a, il n'y a pas disparaît. Mais à mon sens, il ne s'agit plus là de la question précise qui nous est posée.

I don't understand why there's a nous and then suddenly an inversion of il arrive. Could someone break down this sentence and help me understand it? Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Arriver* can mean *to happen*. With that meaning, it's a member of a class of verb that always a take a dummy subject pronoun and have their "real" logical subject expressed as a dative indirect object. See also *falloir* (il nous faut nous dépécher = we must hurry), *aller* in the sense of *suit* (ça me va totalement = suits me fine) or the archaic verb *chaloir* (peu m'en chaut = I care little about this).

You could translate "il nous arrive à tous de dire" as "it happens to us all to say" or more idiomatically "we all sometimes say". The inversion of *il* is purely stylistic, and triggered by the adverb *certainement*.

Comment: Why is the "à" and "de" necessary?

Comment: For the same reasons that is necessary in english : "nous arrive-t-il **à** tous **de** dire" / "It happens **to** us all **to** say"